# Navigational bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I am trying to create a mouseover navigational site.  I have this as my basic design but I wanted to have the main buttons of "Our Team", Locations, and Patient Reources. This is what I had before trying to change to a mouseover scheme...

```
<div class="title">Division of Gastroenterology</div>
</center>
<div class="left_side">  
<p> Staff</p>
<p><b><a href="faculty.html">Faculty</a></b></p>
<p><b><a href="fellows.html">Fellows</a></b></p>

<p>Locations</p>
<p><b><a href="PCAM.html">Perelman Center for Advanced Medicine</a></b></p>
<p><b><a href="PPMC.html">Presbyterian Medical Center</a></b></p>
<p><b><a href="Radnor.html">Penn Medicine at Radnor</a></b></p>

<p>Patient Resources</p>
<p><b><a href="Preps.html"> Procedure Preps</a></b></p>
<p><b><a href="ProviderNumbers.html">Insurance Provider Numbers</a></b></p>
<p><b><a href="Lichtensteindiet.html">IBD Diet</a></b></p>
```

I tried this but am clearly missing something...

Comment: There are different ways of implementing what you want - do you mean horizontal, or vertical? That is, if you want the navigation menu to be horizontal or vertical? And, if you want it to be a popup or inline?

Comment: When you say you are looking for a 'mouseover navigational site' what exactly are you trying to accomplish??

Comment: @lmno, I think she's trying to make a CSS-styled navigation bar - where a sub-menu pops out when you hover over the item in question.

Comment: @LisaLowerHariegel I'm lost as to what this HTML is trying to convey.  If that's what is being shot for, why `p` tags?  What's the purpose of the `center` tag being closed but never opened?  In short, can we get a fiddle with what you're currently working with, or an example of what it is you're shooting for?

Comment: I am trying to create vertical navigation where the sub menu displays when you hover over the main item in javascript not CSS.  The center tag belongs to a title centered higher on the page.

Answer (score 1):

what i have done in the past is hide the dropdown off the screen, then when the user hovers over a link bring the dropdown back into view.

I accomplished this by using unorderd lists like this:

```
 <ul id="nav">
    <li>Home
         <ul>Link 1</ul>
         <ul>Link 2</ul>
         <ul>Link 3</ul>
    </li>
 ...
 </ul>
```

And in the CSS set the main `<li>`'s position to `relative`, the dropdown to `absolute` and `:hover` of the dropdown sets the `left` position to 0

```
/* --- MAIN LINK --- */
#nav li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:35px;
    position:relative;
}

/*--- DROPDOWN ---*/
#nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; /* Hide off-screen when not needed (this is more accessible than display:none;) */
}

#nav li:hover ul{ 
    left:0; /* Display the dropdown on hover */
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are trying to create a navigational bar** as inferred from the information you've posted as well as your general question.

**To implement this fully would require a bit of editing and explanation** - which will be too long to do fully. So, I adapted a nice solution off the web that uses **unordered lists, and CSS** and have made it available to you as well as the article from where it is linked.

Solution Attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/zFsaF/1/

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Staff</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="faculty.html">Faculty</a></li>
                <li><a href="fellows.html">Fellows</a><li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Locations</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="PCAM.html">Perelman Center for Advanced Medicine</a></li>
                <li><a href="PPMC.html">Presbyterian Medical Center</a></li>
                <li><a href="Randor.html">Penn Medicine at Randor</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Patient Resources</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Preps.html">Procedure Preps</a></li>
                <li><a href="ProviderNumbers.html">Insurance Provider Numbers</a></li>
                <li><a href="Lichtensteindiet.html">IBD Diet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #4b545f;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
    }
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #fff;
}   
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
}
nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

Article: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

You can of course adapt this as you need it however you wish.

**NOTE: If some things do not make sense, you can always refer back to the original article, use Google, or consult the very good W3Schools reference:**

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Good luck!

UPDATE:

The OP forgot to mention that the **solution has to be in Javascript**.

**As such, the best place to begin would be to examine tutorials that have already done what is requested.** Here's an excellent place to start:

http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/dropdown-navigation-menus/

Comment: I did update the to use <ul> and such but I need to create the mouseover with javascript not CSS.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have a few - such as using some libraries, but at the end of it all - **they too will use CSS. You can't avoid it.**